# RegEx for email according to wikipedia

Tags: regex

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address

var mailTestRegExp = new RegExp('^[A-Za-z0-9,!#:;<>"\$%&\*\+/=\?\^_`\\{\\|}~-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9,!#:;<>"\\$%&\\*\\+/=\\?\\^_`\{\|}~-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*\.([A-Za-z]{2,})$'

the above works partly.. is it possible to handle email address as expressed in wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

I always use this, try it

```
^(?:[\w\!\#\$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`\{\|\}\~]+\.)*[\w\!\#\$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`\{\|\}\~]+@(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_](?:[a-zA-Z0-9_\-](?!\.)){0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9_-]?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9_](?:[a-zA-Z0-9_\-](?!$)){0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9_]?)|(?:\[(?:(?:[01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:[01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\]))$
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for this:

```
    ^([\w\-\.]+)@((\[([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([\w\-]+\.)+)([a-zA-Z]{2,4}))$
```

Originally Posted by David Lott over at http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=88

Note: RegEx lib is a mixed source for reg exps - watch for the reviews.